# Laravel select2 showing default html multiselect

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap-4, jquery-select2, multi-select

I am currently trying to use select2 in a Laravel project to create a multiselect but Im kinda stuck right of the bat.
The js and css files are linked correctly but when I reload the page it only shows the default multiselect from html.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Titel</title>
    <link href="http://web-application.test/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://web-application.test/select2/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
    });
</script>
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `select2` without `jQuery`. You should get an error in your browser console like `$ / jQuery is not defined`. Check your `script` and `css` file too. I have used all cdn and tested the following code. It works fine. You can try out like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Titel</title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple" style="width:1000px">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> You should use the `scripts` just before the end the `body` tag.

Answer (score 0):

use this approach:
 1- Give an id to your select input
 2- bring your script after the body

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Titel</title>
    <link href="http://web-application.test/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://web-application.test/select2/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" id="select2" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#select2').select2();
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is `select2` with `multiselect` option. set width for the select.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Titel</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2({width:'100%'});
    });
</script>
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```